# How to Force execution: button.setImageResource(R.drawable.x_sign)?

Tags: java, android

[My ticTacToe Assigment picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHMop.jpg)
In onClickListener, I have line `button00.setImageResource(R.drawable.x_sign);`
but it will be executed only when listener is finished.
How can I force this command to execute immediately?

Condition in onClickListener for imageButton is:
`if ((opField[x][y] == 0) && covekNext){  // field is empty and man have turn
    button00.setImageResource(R.drawable.x_sign);
} else return;`

When In this situation I play field 21 ( second row, first column).
button00.setImageResource(R.drawable.x_sign);
Images wouldnt be swaped! blank field stay blank, not X.
Bug or my coding error.

Thanks.

```
    final ImageButton button00 = findViewById(R.id.imageButton00);
    button00.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            x=0;
            y=0;
            if ((opField[x][y] == 0) && covekNext){
                button00.setImageResource(R.drawable.x_sign);
            } else return;
            covekNext = false;
            opField[x][y]= 1;
            if(++opWinLines[0]==3|++opWinLines[3]==3|++opWinLines[6]==3){
                covekWin(); //button00.setImageResource(R.drawable.x_sign); //command not executed
                return;
            }
            if (++zauzeto<9) {
                computerMove(); //button00.setImageResource(R.drawable.x_sign); //command not executed
            } else {
                nereseno(); //button00.setImageResource(R.drawable.x_sign); //command not executed
           }
        }
    });  // button00.setImageResource(R.drawable.x_sign); executed
```

Comment: Just try to add this "button00.setImageResource(R.drawable.x_sign);" before the listener. Or am I missing something?

Comment: It must be done in listener, and it works in most of cases.
But when i do not finish listener "regularly", command is not executed, images are not swaped/refreshed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everybody, thanks a lot!!!!
Everything about this question was my mistake made within some false call in methods: covekWin(); computerWin(); nereseno().

So this part of code is correct, and this question can be erased!

Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for something like this :

```
final ImageButton button00 = findViewById(R.id.imageButton00);
button00.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        x=0;
        y=0;
        if ((opField[x][y] == 0) && covekNext){
            button00.setImageResource(R.drawable.x_sign);
        } else return;
        covekNext = false;
        opField[x][y]= 1;
        if(++opWinLines[0]==3|++opWinLines[3]==3|++opWinLines[6]==3){
            button00.setImageResource(R.drawable.x_sign);
            covekWin(); 
            return;
        }
        if (++zauzeto<9) {
            button00.setImageResource(R.drawable.x_sign);
            computerMove(); 
        } else {
            button00.setImageResource(R.drawable.x_sign);
            nereseno();
       }
    }
});
```

Comment: When first if are true, button00.setImageResource(R.drawable.x_sign);
else return.
So button00.setImageResource(R.drawable.x_sign); are passed in EVERY true case. But images are swaped just if onClick listener not call any of this methods:
covekWin(), computerMove(), nereseno().
Very confusing and iritating. :)

Answer (score 0):

its because u use `return`in your code
clicklisteners suppose to listen to clicks while user works with activity's ui

Comment: In this part of code I do not use return
            if (++zauzeto<9) {
                computerMove(); //button00.setImageResource(R.drawable.x_sign); //command not executed
            } else {
                nereseno(); //button00.setImageResource(R.drawable.x_sign); //command not executed
           }

Comment: I am beginner in this and can You help me with solution of my problem?

Comment: `return` will break the current function and stop everything below it, so if your code hit `return` in the `else` part, the whole `onClick` function will stop right there. Fix your flow, put a breakpoint for debugging to find out what is happening

Answer (score 0):

> It works in most of cases but not always

You are only swapped the `imageResource` in first `if` condition. So when first `else` part is executed, image is not being swapped. If you want this line to execute every time, place it as first line in `onClickListener` as follows.

```
final ImageButton button00 = findViewById(R.id.imageButton00);
button00.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        x=0;
        y=0;

        //Set the imageResource here 
        button00.setImageResource(R.drawable.x_sign);

        if ((opField[x][y] == 0) && covekNext){
        } else return;
        covekNext = false;
        opField[x][y]= 1;
        if(++opWinLines[0]==3|++opWinLines[3]==3|++opWinLines[6]==3){
            covekWin(); 
            return;
        }
        if (++zauzeto<9) {
            computerMove(); 
        } else {
            nereseno();
       }
    }
});
```

Cheers :)

Comment: Is my english realy so bad? :)
Please look better in sample code.

Comment: You want `button00.setImageResource(R.drawable.x_sign);` to execute on every `onClickListener` right?

Comment: It is passed by debuger but images not swaped EVERY time it passed!!!!
So how it is possibile?